# Cannot remove the lock from android

Tags: lock-screens, google-account, locked-out

my issue is when i try use Google services that Allow remote lock and factory reset. if the mobile stolen, then i want to try it and i locked my personal phone successfully it locked by password when i open my device password entry screen appear and when i write the password that i requested from web the device open but i want to remove this lock and i cannot do it, i locked the phone by using Android Device Manager through this [Google link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3265955?hl=en)

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

If adb is detected , Try removing data/system/locksettings.db file and reboot

Following are the detailed steps :

1. adb shell
2. su
3. cd data/system
4. rm locksettings.db
5. rm locksettings.db-wal
6. locksettings.db-shm
7. reboot